# Vue-CLI with webpack add external Css and Js file

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I use `Vue-cli` with `webpack`, and I have problem to call external `js` and `css` file in `index.html`.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>gradana</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/assets/css/hello.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
</html>
```

If I run the code I have error.

[image]

```
Cannot GET /src/assets/css/hello.css
```

Comment: I found solution :
I add code in App.vue 
<style>
  @import './assets/css/hello.css';

Answer (score 2):

As you are using `vue cli`, `assets` folder will be handled by webpack during bundling, and those files within `assets` folder should be included by `js`

[e.g.](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/604) `require('../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')`.

Or you can simply store `CSS` or `JS` files into `/static` folder, all files within `static` folder will be added into `/dist` folder while running app.

[image]

and then call it into `index.html`

**CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/hello.css">
```

**JS**

```
<script src="/static/scripts/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: but this does not work after creating build i tried the same but i got 404 after generation of build any solution to that?